# CSS ::marker pseudo-element why only couple of CSS properties work? why not all?

Tags: css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

why ::marker pseudo-element not support all CSS properties like other pseudo-elements?
can anyone explain me in brief.

Found out today that ::marker pseudo-element not support all CSS properties like background, display, etc but "font-size", "color", and "content" properties are working like charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CSS Lists specification](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-lists-3/#marker-properties) explains:

> NOTE: It is expected that future specifications will extend this list of properties and relax the restriction on which properties can take effect. However at the moment **outside marker box layout is not fully defined, so to avoid future compatibility problems only these properties are allowed**.

Answer (score 1):

Because this selector selects marker of a list item. Like the buller for example. That means that it allows you only to customize the bullet, not the list itself. Thats why you cant apply properties like display, because you are effecting the marker itself. [This can be helpful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker)

Comment: Thanks for answer @Dave111. I know that ::marker used for select marker of a list item but when you use any properties for other pseudo-elements so why only certain CSS properties can be used for ::marker.

Comment: Because you just cant apply any other properties to list markers. You can only change color, font-size and some more that are described in documentation. Thats just how CSS works. Try to imagine, what would you expect to happen if you used for example display:flex and height:100px on the list marker?

Im not sure If I can explain it any better. ::marker effects only the look of the list item marker, not its possitioning.